# How to handle google analytics cookie for ex _ga in jmeter

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, jmeter, client-server

There r some cookies like _ga, jsessionid etc which are part of jmeter recording script but when i replay script these cookies are not handled by cookie manager. How can i send these values in jmeter request . Also i m unable to corelate these cookies . I guess client side js is responsible for sending these cookies.

I m completely blocked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's HTTP Cookie Manager stores **valid** cookies which are coming in [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header, the invalid ones are being discarded.

You can inspect what's going on there by adding/uncommenting the next line in [*log4j2.xml* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

If you see the evidence that cookies are detected but not stored you can try the following:

1. Set `Cookie Policy` to something less restrictive, i.e. `netscape`

   [image]
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=true
   ```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)