# Jmeter response data insufficient to correlate

Tags: r, cookies, jmeter

I am trying to extract `XSRF-TOKEN` from response in Jmeter, however the response does not have this data.  Is there a way to increase the amount of data Jmeter can see returned from the server?

When correlating in Loadrunner using advance trace I can see and correlate this value no problem.

Data returned from Jmeter:

```
type='hidden' id='SAMLRequest' name='SAMLRequest' value='PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c2FtbDJwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVz
dCB4bWxuczpzYW1sMnA9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpwcm90b2NvbCIgQXNz
ZXJ0aW9uQ29uc3VtZXJTZXJ2aWNlVVJMPSJodHRwczovL3BvcnRhbC1zdC5zc2MtZ2N3Y3MuY2Ev
d2NzIiBGb3JjZUF1dGhuPSJmYWxzZSIgSUQ9Ino3YjY3ODhiYi01NTY1LTQ1MjUtODY3Mi05ZDBl
YjAyNzUzOTMiIElzUGFzc2l2ZT0iZmFsc2UiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxOS0wOS0xMVQxNzo1
MjoxMC4zNjBaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpi
aW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIFZlcnNpb249IjIuMCI+PHNhbWwyOklzc3VlciB4bWxuczpzYW1s
Mj0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI+QVBQVElVTS1HQ1dDUy1T
VDwvc2FtbDI6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1sMnA6TmFtZUlEUG9saWN5IEZvcm1hdD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5h
bWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6MS4xOm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6dW5zcGVjaWZpZWQiLz48L3NhbWwycDpBdXRo
blJlcXVlc3Q+'
```

Data returned from Loadrunner:

```
vuser_init.c(112):     HTTP/1.1 302 \r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ep-accountContext=wcs;path=/;HttpOnly\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0MjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjgyMjEwMzcsInJvbG
vuser_init.c(112):     VzIjoiW10iLCJVVUlEIjoiZWdFTEtHNDlReHAyU0VtRG56azdONHdJR1FLIiwic3ViIjoiYWNjZXNzVG9rZW4iLCJp
vuser_init.c(112):     c3MiOiJBbGV4IElsY2hlbmtvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTY4MjM1NDM3fQ.X2z6p-EQSsH_Kd7JsXA_AVSFMmE22zomlwQzOEg
vuser_init.c(112):     R5Ec;path=/;Secure\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: X-XSRF-TOKEN=egELKG49Qxp2SEmDnzk7N4wIGQK;path=/;Secure\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ENDPOINT_ACTIONFLOW={DYNAMIC_DNS}/router/;path=/\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ENDPOINT_DATAMAPPING={DYNAMIC_DNS}/router/;path=/\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ENDPOINT_DECISION={DYNAMIC_DNS}/router/;path=/\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ENDPOINT_DMN={DYNAMIC_DNS}/router/;path=/\r\n
vuser_init.c(112):     Set-Cookie: ENDPOINT_APPLICATION_MANAGEMENT={DYNAMIC_DNS}/;path=
```

Comment: You can check this answer for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520455/how-can-i-extraxt-session-id-and-xsrf-token-through-cookies-in-jmeter

Comment: Another one for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864310/how-to-handle-google-analytics-cookie-for-ex-ga-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this line is the answer:

> Set-Cookie: X-XSRF-TOKEN=egELKG49Qxp2SEmDnzk7N4wIGQK;path=/;Secure\r\n

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
4. That's it, now you should be able to access the `XSRF-TOKEN` value as `${COOKIE_XSRF-TOKEN}` where required

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/)